# Google ads scripts are decreasing Google page speed index score

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-script

Is there a solution to load Google scripts after the page load, so the google page speed index didn't get affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code put a timeout on the heavy javascript codes and if the user scroll it will also run so the content will appears faster

```
var scrollCounter = false;
var pageType = typeof signal !== 'undefined' && signal.Content.ArticleId!=null?'article':'notanarticle';
var cds = /Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent) && document.body.clientWidth < 737 ? 'Mobile' : /Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent) && document.body.clientWidth > 767 ? 'Tablet' : 'Desktop';
if (cds == 'Mobile') {
    //condition for home and section pages
      if(pageType == 'notanarticle') {
       setTimeout(function() {
            if (!scrollCounter) {
                scrollCounter = true;
                console.log('timeout');
                addThirdPartyLibs();
            }
        }, 4000);   
     }//end of condition
    var activityEvents = [
        'keydown', 'touchstart', 'scroll'
    ];
    activityEvents.forEach(function(eventName) {
        document.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
            if (!scrollCounter) {
                scrollCounter = true;
                console.log(window.scrollY);
                addThirdPartyLibs();
            }
        }, true);
    });
} else {
    addThirdPartyLibs();
}

function addThirdPartyLibs() {
    loadGPTJs();

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).